# Get text of a clicked button?

Tags: java, android, button

Hi I am very new to java and android studio. I made a set of buttons in a fragment and used a for loop to set the text of each button....

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < letterBttns.length; i++) {
    letterBttns[i].setText(ethereal[i]);
}
```

What is the best way to get the text of a clicked button? Is there a short way to do it or the only way to do it is calling an `onClick` method for each button?

Because that seems like the long and easy way.

Comment: you don't need to define `onclick` for all. instead, define just one `onClick` call back function and reference buttons to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    .....
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ....
        for (int i = 0; i < letterBttns.length; i++) {
            letterBttns[i].setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String text = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! worked well! hoping you would've explained what's going on but I ended up understanding it!